# @AroundInvoke in a CDI project

Tags: java, interceptor, cdi

There are 3 projects that use CDI. Project A has an Interceptor for transaction control.

Project B uses Project A to save data in a database. When I run these unit tests, everything passes.

Project C uses Project B for integration tests. These tests fails when it finds the @AroundInvoke annotation from Interceptor.

What is going wrong? The interceptor is only in Project B beans.xml.

The exception stacktrace doesn't clear up my mind. It only show a jassist error. Debugging, I found that the problem comes from boostrap.deploybeans() inside Weld. So, I commented the @AroundInvoke in the interceptor class and everything goes fine with tests, but the insert on database. I think that happens because I removed the interceptor that creates transaction for inserts.

The code:

1) There is a project A which defines an annotation and an interceptor for this annotation. Example:

/Annotation/

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Transactional {
}
```

/Interceptor/

```
@Interceptor
@Transactional
public class TransactionalInterceptor implements Serializable {
    …
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        …
    }
    …
}
```

I think this project must have an empty /META-INF/beans.xml.

2) There is another project B that uses the interceptor from project A. Example:

```
public class ProjectBClass {
    …
    @Transactional
    public void interceptorMethod() {
        …
    }
    …
}
```

So I think this project must have a /META-INF/beans.xml that enables the interceptor. Example:

```
<beans>
<interceptors>
<class>br.com.company.projecta.TransactionalInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
</beans>
```

3) Finally, there's a project C that uses the method from project B. Example:

```
public class ProjectCClass {
    …
    private ProjectBClass projectBClass;
    …
    public void testerMethod() {
        …
        this.projectBClass.interceptorMethod();
        …
    }
    …
}
```

I am not sure if it must have a /META-INF/beans.xml.

4) In this same project, there is an integration test which tests the method. Example:

```
public class ProjectCClassTest {
   …
   @Test
   public void test() {
      ProjectCClass projectCClass = new ProjectCClass();
      projectCClass.testerMethod();
      …
      Assert.assertEquals(…);
   }
   …
}
```

Comment: Why does it fail? Does it throw an Exception? An expected result is not returned? What is the problem that occurs in the test, in other words?

Comment: Please post from a single account; if you have more than one, they can be [merged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste).

Answer (score 0):

You need `META-INF/beans.xml` in all projects (packaged as .jar)

You should not instantiate the classes yourself. If you do, they are not CDI managed. Let CDI instantiated them. For example [look here](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/WeldInJavaSE#comment13037).